# Android API implement by C or Java?

Tags: android, api

I want to backport a JellyBean 4.1 API to 4.0 for my app. And that would much harder if the source is not in Java.

Where I can check out that?

To be specific, I want to backport this api [Accessibility Service](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#A11y)

Answer (score 1):

`AccessibilityService`'s implementation is not a framework class (e.g., `Activity`), but part of the core OS. You cannot backport it for an app the way that, say, ActionBarSherlock backported the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just look at the Jelly Bean source code? http://source.android.com/source/index.html

Comment: I would if I can read them online. I don't want to download it at the moment considering my network access speed